# Voice call returning object is missing dateCreated value

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api

I'm making an express/nodejs application that after a DB trigger makes several calls to notify that something special has happened. Calls are made using Twilio for NodeJS. After placing the call, returned object has several properties with null value, including `dateCreated` and `dateUpdated`, which are the ones I need.

Call code:

```js
MyModule.makeCall = async (datos) => {
    try {
        callData = await client.calls.create({
            twiml: "<Response> " +
                "<Say>Blablabla.</Say>" +
                '<Pause length="1"/>' +
                '<Gather input="dtmf" timeout="15" numDigits="1" action="my_webhook_url" method="POST">'+
                "<Say>More Blablabla.</Say>" +
                "</Gather>"+
                "</Response>",
            to: datos.toNumber,
            from: datos.fromNumber
        }); 
        return callData;
    } catch (error) {
        ...
    }
}
```

**Edited 2:** Use code:

```js
const InterfazTwilio = require('../modules/twilio.methods');
callData = await InterfazTwilio.makeCall(callParams);
console.log(callData);
```

And this is the object I'm getting from the call:

```json
{
  sid: 'XXXXX',
  dateCreated: null,
  dateUpdated: null,
  parentCallSid: null,
  accountSid: 'YYYYY',
  to: '+98765432109',
  toFormatted: '+98765432109',
  from: '+12345678901',
  fromFormatted: '(123) 456-7890',
  phoneNumberSid: 'ZZZZ',
  status: 'queued',
  startTime: null,
  endTime: null,
  duration: null,
  price: null,
  priceUnit: 'USD',
  direction: 'outbound-api',
  answeredBy: null,
  apiVersion: '2010-04-01',
  forwardedFrom: null,
  groupSid: null,
  callerName: null,
  queueTime: '0',
  trunkSid: null,
  uri: '/2010-04-01/Accounts/YYYYY/Calls/XXXXX.json',
  subresourceUris: {
    feedback: '/2010-04-01/Accounts/YYYYY/Calls/XXXXX/Feedback.json',
    user_defined_messages: '/2010-04-01/Accounts/YYYYY/Calls/XXXXX/UserDefinedMessages.json',
    notifications: '/2010-04-01/Accounts/YYYYY/Calls/XXXXX/Notifications.json',
    recordings: '/2010-04-01/Accounts/YYYYY/Calls/XXXXX/Recordings.json',
    streams: '/2010-04-01/Accounts/YYYYY/Calls/XXXXX/Streams.json',
    payments: '/2010-04-01/Accounts/YYYYY/Calls/XXXXX/Payments.json',
    user_defined_message_subscriptions: '/2010-04-01/Accounts/YYYYY/Calls/XXXXX/UserDefinedMessageSubscriptions.json',
    siprec: '/2010-04-01/Accounts/YYYYY/Calls/XXXXX/Siprec.json',
    events: '/2010-04-01/Accounts/YYYYY/Calls/XXXXX/Events.json',
    feedback_summaries: '/2010-04-01/Accounts/YYYYY/Calls/FeedbackSummary.json'
}
```

If making a test call with test credentials, returned object has these properties filled while maintaining same call status (`queued`). I thought at least `dateCreated` would reflect the moment where my call has been placed on Twilio system but I'm getting a null value. I've tried using "Call status changes" option, linking this to a callback webhook but my method has never been called.

Is it possible to retrieve dateCreated when invoking `client.calls.create()` method? Am I missing something here, about `dateCreated`, call status or call status changing?

I've read in the docs ([here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/webhooks/voice-webhooks#call-status-callbacks)) that call status callbacks are only called AFTER the call ends, which explains why I haven't received any request when the call is in progress, but I haven't received any request in the webhook I've configured for this purpose. I guess I'm missing something else.

I'm not using a trial account, just in case it could be related.

Answer (score 0):

I would check your serializer. View the returned json payload from Twilio before being deserialized (aka raw). It seems you have many null values. Perhaps your serializer is expecting a different case than is being provided in the response payload and skipping it?

This page shows what the payload should look like: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/make-calls?code-sample=code-make-an-outbound-call-to-a-phone-number&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=4.x

Comment: I've added a bit more code to my question. I'm only "echoing" what Trilio returns: it's not that I don't have those properties in the returning object but that they're not filled with a valid value. The JSON object I'm posting is the one that Twilio returns.

Comment: One clarification...Status callbacks occur during a variety of phrases of the call depending on which callback you subscribed to. The "completed" callback occurs at the end of a call. Others occur before the end of the call. Ringing occurs while "ringing". "Answered" occurs once the call is answered. https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/webhooks/voice-webhooks#:~:text=By%20default%2C%20Twilio%20will%20send,or%20statusCallbackEvent%20attribute%20in%20TwiML.

Comment: You're talking about call status: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource#call-status-values. I woud guess that `dateUpdated` would be filled after certain status is reached but documentation explicitly says about `dateCreated` that it is "The date and time in GMT that this resource was created" (https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource#call-properties). So why is this date null after creating the Call?

Comment: Please check the Twilio Console for this call. The Twilio Console will show the data Twilio sent to your webhook. This way you can verify that Twilio is actually sending the data. Please note there is also a Timestamp attribute - Time of the event, conformant to UTC ISO 8601 Timestamp.

Comment: Please note that I'm not talking about data received when invoking a webhook, but data received when invoking the `call` method from the API. I mean, when creating a Call Resource. Objects are different in both places though they have several properties in common, but Timestamp is not one of those.  I'm using a statusCallback to finally get dateCreated, but I want to know why I can't have this date the way I supposed I could get it when I read the docs.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. I apologize as I was down the wrong track. If you are invoking the call, then you already know what time the request occurred (as you made the request) and will need to collect and track it yourself. The typical mode is to create the call (track whatever information you need in your app) and then use webhooks to receive additional call status events.